# Eliminar el " + " al finalizar antes de " = "

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una de todos los números con la función "for" pero al finalizar me da el resultado que deseo pero con una formulación "+ =", desearía quitar el "+" al final de la operación pero no encuentro el método para hacerlo.

```
num_sum = 0
for number in range(1, num_limite + 1):
    num_sum = num_sum + number
    print(number, end=' + ')

print("=", num_sum)
```

Comment: `print(number, end=' + ' if number !=num_limite else "")`

Comment: No sabía que se podían anidar las condicionales de esa forma, muchas gracias!

Comment: eso se llama operador ternario :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de resolverlo es tener el separador ("," en este caso) en una variable separada.

Defino la variable `pre` para contener lo que hay que imprimir **antes** de cada valor.

En la primera iteración, no debo imprimir nada antes del valor, por lo que inicializo `pre=''`.

En las siguientes iteraciones tengo que imprimir una coma antes del valor, por lo que cambio la variable `pre=','`.

```
num_sum = 0
num_limite = 10
pre = ''
for number in range(1, num_limite + 1):
    num_sum = num_sum + number
    print(f'{pre}{number}', end = '')
    pre = ','

print("=", num_sum)
```

produce:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10= 55

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El costo de reasignar `pre` en cada iteración es menor que tener que preguntar primero y asignar después.

Answer (score 0):

Otra idea. En lugar de imprimir el + después de cada número (salvo en el último) puedes imprimir el + *delante* de cada número (salvo el primero).

Y para evitar tener que mirar con una condición si estás o no en el primero, puedes procesar ese primer número fuera del bucle, y todos los restantes dentro, que ya se procesarían todos de igual forma.

Es decir:

```
num_inicial = 1
num_limite = 10

num_sum = num_inicial
print(num_inicial, end='')
for number in range(num_inicial+1, num_limite + 1):
    num_sum = num_sum + number
    print(f'+{number}', end = '')

print("=", num_sum)
```

Sale:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10= 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Un planteamiento mejor del problema es crear primero la cadena que se quiere imprimir.

```py
num_limite = 10

sumandos = list(range(1, num_limite + 1))
cadena_suma = ' + '.join(str(i) for i in sumandos)

print(f"{cadena_suma} = {sum(sumandos)}")
```

Comment: No hay necesidad de convertir el rango en una lista. Pero buena idea!

Comment: Ademas, puedes usar la funcion map en lugar de comprensiones. map(str, sumandos). map aplica la funcion pasada como primer argumento a cada item del iterable pasado como segundo argumento. Funciona similar a una comprension de generador.

Comment: Siempre que un _iterable_ se vaya a usar más de una vez, es apropiado clonarlo o convertirlo en una lista estática. El caso de `Range` es especial: aunque sea iterable no se _consume_ por recorrerlo al completo. (Por _clonar_ me refiero a usar `itertools.tee`). En cuanto al `map`, también opino que está más claro desde un punto de vista próximo a la _programación funcional_, pero hoy en día se considera poco _pythónico_ y no se aconseja usarlo: <http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0141>.

Comment: Pero convertirlo en una lista hace que cada numero se guarde en la lista. Mientras que si dejas el range puro, python se encarga de hacer los calculos matematicos para cada valor. En pocas palabras, consume más memoria convertirlo en una lista. En ese caso la mejor alternativa es clonarlo o dejarlo así.

Comment: Que lastima, map es una función muy buena. Por que sería poco pythonico? Es solo un poco menos claro que la comprensión de generador. Si es por eso, creo que la obsesión de la comunidad de Python por la claridad está yendo un poco lejos. Map ahorra unos buenos caracteres que aparecerian al cohete.

Comment: Ya digo que `Range` es especial, un iterable `O(1)` que puedes usar varias veces sin problemas. Pero al crear el iterable `sumandos` que iba a ser usado dos veces, es mejor convertirlo en lista. Se puede refactorizar de muchas formas, pero me ha parecido más legible así. En cuanto a las razones de porqué `map` no es _pythónico_ habría que preguntarle a _nuestro amado líder_: <https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196>

Comment: No es por ofender, pero pareciera que no leíste mi comentario. Por que es mejor convertirlo el lista en lugar de clonarlo?

Comment: Principalmente, por  _legibilidad_, pero también por eficiencia. `tee` almacena internamente los elementos obtenidos del iterador clonado para dárselos a los clones hijos. Si iteras primero por un clon, el resto de clones van a iterar igual que si tuvieran una lista.  `tee` es más para iterar en paralelo, no en secuencia.

Comment: Volviendo a lo anterior, entonces si tengo un rango range(10000000000). Me conviene convertirlo a lista cuando lo uso varias veces? Para mi eso no tiene sentido. Estarias almacenando en memoria ese monton grande de numeros por un poco de velocidad.

Comment: Sí, puedes usar  `range`, pero necesitarás usar al menos dos, o aplicar algún truco como meter el operador walrus `:=` en el generador.

Comment: Por que no aprovechar que range es uno de los iterables que no se agotan y crearlo una sola vez? La cadena es un ejemplo de otro iterable que no se agota.

Comment: Estoy algo perdido. Claro que puedes aprovechar range para lo que dices. Pero en el código del que se supone que estamos hablando `sumandos` es un iterable que se crea a partir de range y sí que es un iterable que se agota y que se está usando dos veces. Ya añadiré un código que usa range y que sólo recorre `sumandos` una vez.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131155/discussion-between-dante-s-and-chemacortes).